# How to rearrange a multidimensional array in a custom order by keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm looking for a way to change the order of an array by keys by using a different array which contains the keys and the new index of this key. The order will be dynamic so ASC or DESC sorting will not work.

Is there a function to sort an array this way?

**the original array(which need to be rearranged)**

```
{
    4 =>  'this should move to fifth place',
    2 =>  'this should not move',
    5 =>  'this should move to end of the array',
    9 =>  'this should move to fourth place',
    77 => 'this should move to beginning',
    10 => 'this should move to third place',
 }
```

**array sortIndex(the array with the new order)**

```
{
   key of other array => index/order,
   //
   4  => 5,
   77 => 1,
   2  => 2,
   9  => 4,
   10 => 3,
   5  => 6,
}
```

Comment: `array_combine($keys, $values)`

Comment: Sadly the duplicates are NOT the same , so anybody an idea how to do this?

Comment: Sadly you don't try anything from duplicates: `asort($b);$new = array_replace($b, $a);`